# Python format value as a valid date

Tags: python, date

suppose I have a report that has the following name:

"REPORT NAME 0331" , where 0331 refers to March 31th, 2020.

I was able to extract the 0331 through slicing:

`name[-4:]`

But I would like to now format 0331 into a valid date (i.e., that I can then use to compare vs the date of another report, and determine which report is older).

EDIT: The format should be "2020-MM-DD"

How would that work?

Comment: I think you could just use that substring, `0331`, to compare as long as the dates all fall within the same year. `0331 < 0401 == True`

Comment: That might actually work, still curious about how to do it though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work for what you described.

```
import datetime from datetime

month_date = '%m%d'
raw_value = '0331'

date = datetime.strptime(month_day_format, raw_value)
date = date.replace(year=2020)

report_date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

The `report_date` captures the formatted date string.

Useful links to the datatime functions used:

- strptime - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime
- strftime - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime
- replace - https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior), e.g.:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('0331', '%m%d')
# datetime.datetime(1900, 3, 31, 0, 0)
```

and then you can use the `datetime` object as detailed in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
d = name[-4:]
res = datetime(2020, int(d[:2]),int(d[2:]))
```